# Factory instance not creating a new deferred

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, twisted.internet

I am pretty new to Twisted, so I am sure this is a rookie mistake. I have built a simple server which receives a message from the client and upon receipt of message the server fires a callback which prints the message to the console.

At first instance, the server works as expected. Unfortunately, when I start up a  second client I get the follow error "twisted.internet.defer.AlreadyCalledError." It was my understanding that the factory would make a new instance of the deferred i.e. the new deferred wouldn't have been called before?

Please see the code below. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
import sys
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import defer

class LockProtocol(Protocol):

  lockData = ''

  def dataReceived(self, data):
    self.lockData += data

    if self.lockData.endswith('??'):
      self.lockDataReceived(self.lockData)

  def lockDataReceived(self, lockData):
    self.factory.lockDataFinished(lockData)

class LockServerFactory(ServerFactory):

  protocol = LockProtocol  

  def __init__(self):
    self.deferred = defer.Deferred() # Initialise deferred

  def lockDataFinished(self, lockData):
      self.deferred.callback(lockData)

  def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
      self.deferred.errback(reason)


def main():

  HOST = '127.0.0.1' # localhost
  PORT = 10001

  def got_lockData(lockData):
    print "We have received lockData. It is as follows:", lockData

  def lockData_failed(err):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'The lockData download failed.'
    errors.append(err)


  factory = LockServerFactory()

  from twisted.internet import reactor

  #  Listen for TCP connections on a port, and use our factory to make a protocol instance for each new connection

  port = reactor.listenTCP(PORT,factory)

  print 'Serving on %s' %  port.getHost()

  # Set up callbacks

  factory.deferred.addCallbacks(got_lockData,lockData_failed)

  reactor.run() # Start the reactor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that there is only one `LockServerFactory` ever created in your program:

```
factory = LockServerFactory()
```

However, as many `LockProtocol` instances are created as connections are accepted.  If you have per-connection state, the place to put it is on `LockProtocol`.

It looks like your "lock data completed" event is not a one-off so a `Deferred` is probably not the right abstraction for this job.

Instead of a `LockServerFactory` with a `Deferred` that fires when that event happens, perhaps you want a multi-use event handler, perhaps custom built:

```
class LockServerFactory(ServerFactory):

  protocol = LockProtocol  

  def __init__(self, lockDataFinished):
    self.lockDataFinished = lockDataFinished

 factory = LockServerFactory(got_lockData)
```

(Incidentally, notice that I've dropped `clientConnectionFailed` from this implementation: that's a method of *`ClientFactory`*.  It will never be called on a server factory.)